# How to iterate several dataframe row by row and modified one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am stuck with a loop that is not working for me. What I want is to extract values from dataframes based in a condition to my final dataframe.

I have:

Final Dataframe:

```
final = {'code': ['A001','A002','A003'],
          'reg': ['2234','3432', '6578'],
          'name': ['Solutions BS', 'Flying 23', 'Fast Co'],
          'df2_code': ['','',''],
          'df2_name': ['', '', ''],
          'df3_code': ['','',''],
          'df3_name': ['', '', '']}
```

This dataframe must be fill. Specifically, the columns with the prefix df2, df3,...

It must be filled with the 'code' and 'name' column of other dataframes that contains the same firsts three column names of the 'final dataframe' (code, reg, name). A condition applies to fill, the 'reg' number must be the same in both dataframes.

An example of the others:

```
df2 = {'code': ['P001','A002','P003'],
          'reg': ['2234','3432', '9978'],
          'name': ['Chips 23', 'Flying 23', 'American99']}
```

So, until now, the product of this logic would be:

```
final = {'code': ['A001','A002','A003'],
              'reg': ['2234','3432', '6578'],
              'name': ['Solutions BS', 'Flying 23', 'Fast Co'],
              'df2_code': ['P001','A002',''],
              'df2_name': ['Chips 23', 'Flying 23', '']}
```

But, the problem is a little more complex. There are duplicates in the df2 of the 'reg' numbers which serve as conditions. So 'df2' actually is:

```
df2 = {'code': ['P001','A002','P003', 'B004'],
              'reg': ['2234','3432', '9978', '2234'],
              'name': ['Chips 23', 'Flying 23', 'American99', NaN]}
```

And this must be taken into account by adding the 'code' and the 'name' of the two in the same cells. The product would be:

```
final = {'code': ['A001','A002','A003'],
              'reg': ['2234','3432', '6578'],
              'name': ['Solutions BS', 'Flying 23', 'Fast Co'],
              'df2_code': ['P001&B004','A002',''],
              'df2_name': ['Chips 23', 'Flying 23', '']}
```

Until now, I have written this code for only one dataframe (df2) and it takes too many time as the final df has 200.000+ rows (I have 5 df to scan but these are tinier):

```
for i, row in final.iterrows():
    for j, inrow in df2.iterrows():
        if row['reg'] == inrow['reg']:
            if final['df2_code'].iloc[i] == '':
                final['df2_code'].iloc[i] = str(inrow['code'])
            else:
                final['df2_code'].iloc[i] += '&' + str(inrow['code'])
            if inrow['name'] is None:
                continue
            else: 
                if final['df2_name'].iloc[i] == '':
                    final['df2_name'].iloc[i] = str(inrow['name'])
                else:
                    final['df2_name'].iloc[i] += '&' + str(inrow['name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `Series.cat` + `groupby`:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['P001','A002','P003', 'B004'],
                    'reg': ['2234','3432', '9978', '2234'],
                    'name': ['Chips 23', 'Flying 23', 'American99', float('nan')]})

agg_df = (df2.assign(name = lambda x: x["name"].fillna(""))
             .groupby(['reg'])
             .agg({'code': lambda g: g.str.cat(sep="&"), 
                   'name': 'max'})
             .add_prefix("df2_")
         )

agg_df
#        df2_code    df2_name
# reg
# 2234  P001&B004    Chips 23
# 3432       A002   Flying 23
# 9978       P003  American99
```

To iterate across data frames, run horizontal merge from list of data frames (using elementwise `zip` in list comprehension for prefixes).

```py
# LIST OF AGGREGATED DATA FRAMES
dfs = [
       (df.assign(name = lambda x: x["name"].fillna(""))
          .groupby(['reg'])
          .agg({'code': lambda g: g.fillna("").str.cat(sep="&"), 
                'name': max})
          .add_prefix(f"{nm}_")
       ) 
       for df, nm 
       in zip([df2, df3, df4, df5], ["df2", "df3", "df4", "df5"])
     ]

# HORIZONTAL MERGE ON "reg"
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: omg! thank you very much, your answer blew my mind. 